# Cada vez que aumento un producto a mi tabla 2 el stock de mis productos se reinicia? como puedo evitarl

Tags: php, java

TENGO ESTE ARCHIVO LLAMADO venta.php

```
<main class="table">
        <section class="table__header">
            <h1>Venta de productos</h1>
            <form class="header__search" onsubmit="buscarProducto(event)">
                <input type="text" name="productId" class="header__input" placeholder="Buscar producto por ID" id="txtBuscar">
                <button type="submit"><i class='bx bx-plus header__icon'></i></button>
            </form>


            <script>
                let stockOriginal = {}; // Almacena el stock original de cada producto
                let stockDisponible = {}; // Almacena el stock disponible de cada producto
                let productosSeleccionados = {}; // Almacena la cantidad seleccionada de cada producto

                function buscarProducto(event) {
                    event.preventDefault(); // Evitar el envío del formulario (recarga de la página)

                    const productId = document.getElementById("txtBuscar").value;

                    // Realizar una solicitud AJAX para obtener los detalles del producto por su ID
                    fetch(`get_product_details.php?id=${productId}`)
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            if (data) {
                                // Actualizar la tabla con los detalles del producto encontrado
                                const newRow = `
                        <tr>
                            <td>${data.id_producto}</td>
                            <td>${data.name_product}</td>
                            <td>S/.${data.precio_product}</td>
                            <td>${data.stock_product}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn-table_edit" onclick="agregarATabla2(${data.id_producto}, '${data.name_product}', ${data.precio_product}, ${data.stock_product})">
                                <i class='bx bx-plus header__icon'></i>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>`;
                                document.getElementById("searchResultsBody").innerHTML = newRow;
                            } else {
                                alert("Producto no encontrado");
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
                }

                function agregarATabla2(id, nombre, precio, stock) {
                    // Verificar si el producto ya está en la tabla 2
                    const existingRow = document.getElementById(`row_${id}`);
                    if (existingRow) {
                        // Actualizar la cantidad seleccionada del producto existente
                        const input = document.getElementById(`input_${id}`);
                        const cantidad = parseInt(input.value);
                        input.value = cantidad + 1; // Incrementar la cantidad seleccionada
                        // También podrías agregar aquí la lógica de validación para no exceder el stock disponible
                    } else {
                        if (!stockOriginal.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                            // Si el producto no está en la tabla 2, guardar sus detalles y stock
                            stockOriginal[id] = stock;
                            stockDisponible[id] = stock;
                            productosSeleccionados[id] = 1; // Inicializa la cantidad seleccionada en 1 por defecto
                        }

                        // Agregar el producto a la tabla 2
                        const newRow = `
                            <tr id="row_${id}">
                                <td>${id}</td>
                                <td>${nombre}</td>
                                <td>S/.${precio}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="container-input">
                                        <button class="btn-m" id="decrement_${id}" onclick="decrementar(${id}, ${stockDisponible[id]})"> - </button>
                                        <input type="number" min="1" max="${stockDisponible[id]}" value="${productosSeleccionados[id]}" id="input_${id}">
                                        <button class="btn-m" id="increment_${id}" onclick="incrementar(${id}, ${stockDisponible[id]})"> + </button>
                                    </div>                            
                                </td>
                                <td>Eliminar</td>
                            </tr>`;
                        document.getElementById("searchResultsBody2").innerHTML += newRow;
                        validarEntrada(id, stockDisponible[id]);
                    }
                }



                function validarEntrada(id, stock) {
                    const input = document.getElementById(`input_${id}`);
                    input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
                        let valor = parseInt(input.value);
                        if (valor > stock) {
                            input.value = stock;
                        } else if (valor < 1 || isNaN(valor)) {
                            input.value = 1;
                        }
                    });

                    // Agregar validación para evitar dejar el input vacío
                    input.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
                        if (input.value === '') {
                            input.value = 1;
                        }
                    });
                }

                function decrementar(id, stock) {
                    const input = document.getElementById(`input_${id}`);
                    let valor = parseInt(input.value);
                    if (valor > 1) {
                        valor--;
                        input.value = valor;
                    }
                }

                function incrementar(id, stock) {
                    const input = document.getElementById(`input_${id}`);
                    let valor = parseInt(input.value);
                    if (valor < stock) {
                        valor++;
                        input.value = valor;
                    }
                }
            </script>

        </section>

        <section class="table__body">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                        <th>Accion</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="searchResultsBody">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>

        <section class="table__body">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                        <th>Accion</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="searchResultsBody2">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>
```

OTRO ARCHIVO QUE SE ENCARGA DE OBTENER LOS DATOS DE MI BASE DE DATOS LLAMADO get_product_details es el encargado de buscar en la base de datos.

```
<?php
include "model/bd_conexion.php";

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $productId = $_GET['id'];

    // Consulta para obtener los detalles del producto por su ID
    $query = "SELECT id_producto, name_product, precio_product, stock_product FROM productos WHERE id_producto = $productId";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    // Verificar si se encontró el producto y devolver los detalles como JSON
    if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo json_encode($row);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(null); // Producto no encontrado
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(null); // ID no proporcionado
}
?>
```

MOSTRARE LAS IMAGENES DEL PROBLEMA VOY A AGREGAR DOS PRODUCTOS A MI TABLA 2 CON EL STOCK DE 3 CADA UNO Y LUEGO, AGREGARE OTRO PRODUCTO Y REINICIARA LA CANTIDAD DE LOS PRODUCTOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AHORA CUANDO YA EH AGREGADO EL OTRO PRODUCTO REINICIA LA CANTIDAD QUE YA HABIA INSERTADO EN MI INPUT DE STOCK

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NO MANTIENE EL STOCK ESE ES MI PROBLEMA